# App.Config does cannot access section specified

Tags: c#

http://pastebin.com/QaCCM2Zv

I have a config file in the above link, every time i try to access the section '**InventoryFactory**' using this code:

var config = (ObjectFactoryConfiguration)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("**InventoryFactory**");

it returns an error:

An exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll but was not handled in user code

***Additional information: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for InventoryFactory: Could not load type 'WDG.ObjectFactory.ObjectFactoryConfiguration' from assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.***

Any idea guys? Thanks :

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so already you probably need to set up a custom configuration section handler to parse the "InventoryFactory" section into your "ObjectFactoryConfiguration" object.  The error message indicates that the runtime is trying to load the "WDG.ObjectFactory.ObjectFactoryConfiguration" class from the "System.Configuration" assembly which wouldn't contain any of your custom classes.

...Also, you want to specify the assembly in the section, if you look at the line right above yours:`<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>`  you can see at the end there the "log4net" assembly has been specified. Try putting the name of your assembly which contains the "ObjectFactoryConfiguration" class in the type attribute as well.

Comment: Additional information: I had no problem with this on the testing it on the browser, however,  when I do unit tests that's the time it occurs.

Comment: Is the config file included in your unit test project?